# how to handle table index out of bound for iphone

Tags: iphone

when i scroll table view data then i am getting this error

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (5)'
2010-07-31 12:24:50.297 Wat2Eat[3105:207] Stack: (
```

how to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an invalid index in your array. The error message is clearly stating that you have an array with 5 items and you are trying to access more than this - array indices are 0 based so the maximum is 4.